# I need to post a variable from jquery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I've included a snippet of the code I'm trying to get to work. As you can see I have a table which is generated from a jquery input on a previous page. The table can have from 1 to 10 rows in it. I need some way of posting the number of rows from jquery to PHP. I've seen ajax implementations, but they don't seem to work. I need it to post the value when I click on the submit button. I've also tried using:

```
$.post('password_processor_save.php',{jqvar:variable})
```

without it working. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how ajax works, but I'm just kind of lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#save_passwords').show();
    });
</script>
<?php
}
if(isset($_GET['multiple'])) {
?>                      
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#numberOfFields').show();
        $('#option1').show();
        $("div#option1").click(function(){

        numberOfFields = $('#numberOfFields').val();
    //  $("div#bar1").css({'background-color':'yellow','border':'1mm solid black','height':'50px','width':barwidth + "px",'background-image':'url(\'moneySign.jpg\')'});

        if(numberOfFields > 10) { $('#explanation').html('You may not create more than 10 passwords at a time.') }
        else {
            $('#numberOfFields').hide();
            $('#option1').hide();
            $('#save_passwords').show();
            //Count the number of fields that are to be present based upon the user input.
            var count = 0;
            for(var num=1;num<=numberOfFields;num++) { 
            var TD = '\
</tr>\
                        <tr>\
                            <td>\
                                <input type="text" name="password_input' + num + '" id="password_input' + num + '" />\
                            </td>\
                            <td>\
                                <input type="text" name="group_input' + num + '" id="group_input' + num + '" />\
                            </td>\
                            <td>\
                                <select name="belongs_input' + num + '" id="belongs_input' + num + '">\
                                    <option>Just me<option>\
                                </select>\
                            </td>\
                            <td>\
                                <input type="text" name="name_input' + num + '" id="name_input' + num + '" />\
                            </td>\
                            <td>\
                                Yes<input type="radio" name="choice' + num + '" id="choice_input" /> No<input type="radio" name="choice' + num + '" id="choice_input" />\
                            </td>\
</tr>\
<tr>\
';  
               $('div#display_categories table').append(TD);
           }
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="jqvar"></input>
                    <input type="submit" name="save_passwords" id="save_passwords" value="Save Passwords" />
                </form>

                <input name="numberOfFields" id="numberOfFields">
                <div id="option1">
                    <div class="bigText">Click here to add passwords</div><br>
                </div>
                <div id="explanation"></div>
            </div> <!-- End of boxWrapper div -->
        </body>
        <div class="bigBoldFont">
        </div>
        <?php require_once('headerFooter/footer.php'); ?>
    </div><!-- end of boxWrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the part were the form and the table tags are "opened"?

Comment: I didn't include the entire code here. The opening form tag is before the table tag.